# What is the meaning of "it is written on the blackboard"

Tags: grammar

Is it a passive and means that we write it on the blackboard?

Or it is an adjective?

Comment: The question isn't clear. What the point of your question? **Read it again then revise or amplify**

Comment: It means something has been written on the blackboard. And yes, it is passive voice.

Answer (score 0):

The **verb - is written -** refers to the subject **- it -** in passive voice.

Here's an example of where the verb "to write" takes form of an adjective:

> The documents and the **written** text were then scanned.

In this sentance, the word *written* complements the noun, *text,* thus gramatically making it an adjective.

Hope this clarifies it a bit.